# What is an alternative of a4j:JsFunction in JSF 2.0?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf, jsf-2.2

I am new to JSF 2.0.

My current project is build on JSF 1.3 and Richfaces 3.3.
We are trying to migrate to JSF 2.0.
There is limitation to not use  Richface 3.3 or 4.0 in Current Project or any third party tool/library. Our goal is to only use JSF 2.0 functionality/feature.

In my project there is lot of use of

```
<a4j:jsFunction data="action" oncomplete="JavaScriptFunction(data); >
<a4j:actionaram name="nm" assignTo="#beanName.methodName"> </a4j:actionparam>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

I want to remove this type of `a4j:jsFunction` with `h:commandButton` or 
any jsf 2.0 standard mechanism.

I am not able to find out best way to call Bean function which return some value and assign this return value to JavaScript function.

Comment: I think rich:componentControl is what you need please refer : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_componentControl.html

Comment: We are trying to remove Richfaces3.3 and not able to use Richfaces 4.0. We can just use JSF 2.0 functionality.

Comment: Well, the reason RichFaces and other -Faces exist is to provide components JSF doesn't have. Wouldn't it better to get RichFaces 4 working?

Answer (score 1):

JSF 1.3? I thought 1.2 was the latest?

On to your question. The idea to only use JSF 2.x is invalid and you should have the decision maker reconsider because skimping on OmniFaces will impede your productivity and the general code quality.

The way I see it you have three choices:

1. OmniFaces
2. Click button with display:none using javascript. Said button can have f:ajax as a child
3. Rip `o:commandScript` http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript it's open source.

I can fully understand that a company today says no to Primefaces or Richfaces and honestly I would recommend it for many applications. Omnifaces however is to be seen as a proper for JSF.

Comment: thanks karl....In h:commandButton case how to get return data from the called method bean and assign the value to the Javascript function

Comment: you need to have the f:ajax render something. That something can indeed include a script that you can author with el expressions to make it dynamic. After each programmatic click render that area and let the script run.

Alternative way is to use h:outputText with escape=false